# JavaFX RadioButton setSelected() not working

Tags: javafx-8

I'm creating a JavaFX FXML application and haven't been able to use the `setSelected()` method to set one of two radio buttons by default in a toggle group. The toggle group is functioning normally, so it appears the radio button variables are being set correctly. However, `radio1` is not selected as expected.

Following are the relevant sections of my application.

**System Information**

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_171; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.171-b11
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_171-b11
System: Mac OS X version 10.13.4 running on x86_64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="inventory.view.AddPartController">
   <fx:define>
       <ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup" />
   </fx:define>
   <children>
      <RadioButton fx:id="radio1" mnemonicParsing="false"
          onAction="#handleRadio1" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0"
          text="radio1" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup"
          AnchorPane.rightAnchor="125.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="radio2" mnemonicParsing="false"
          onAction="#handleRadio2" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0"
          text="radio2" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup"
          AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller**

```
package inventory.view;

import inventory.InventorySystem;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class AddPartController {

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup toggleGroup;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton radio1;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton radio2;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        radio1 = new RadioButton();
        radio1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        radio1.setSelected(true);

        radio2 = new RadioButton();
        radio2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinitializing the radio button.  The FXML will inject the reference, you are then overriding it.  You also define the toggle group in your FXML - so you don't need that either.

Change your code to look like this:

```
 @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        radio1.setSelected(true);
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you. Can't tell you how many hours I've spent searching for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialize the buttons again . These lines would be enough.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    radio1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    radio1.setSelected(true);
    radio2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
}
```